# how can I find all the websites on a particular IP?

Tags: ip, server, domain

When I try to find websites hosted on a specific IP using one of the online Reverse IP Lookup tools, I only get one website, but when I use Sub-domain enumeration, I find several websites on the same IP
Why does this happen? And how can I find all the websites on a particular IP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find all domains hosted on a single host?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22949), [Finding web application on webserver having only IP](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/171786)

Comment: Or, https://superuser.com/questions/1543395/check-how-many-domains-are-hosted-on-a-linux-server-server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse IP Lookup usually returns the domains under the primary Top Level Domains hosted on a given  IP address (since that is what is usually placed in the [PTR](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-ptr-record/) record), not a complete list of websites hosted at the IP. This typically does not include sub-domains since the subdomains are not directly under the primary top level domains.

> And how can I find all the websites on a particular IP?

If you want to enumerate all websites including sub-domains, you can try using a reverse IP lookup to find the domains hosted on that IP and then enumerate sub-domains for all of them.

Comment: Is there a command line in windows for reverse IP lookup? Example @nobody

Comment: @alex https://serverfault.com/questions/41064/whats-the-command-line-utility-in-windows-to-do-a-reverse-dns-look-up

Comment: I still get the same problem when I use nslookup I get only one website hosted on IP  but when I use this service https://pentest-tools.com/information-gathering/find-subdomains-of-domain
I get many website hosted on the same IP

Comment: @alex That site does sub-domain enumeration. Reverse IP lookup and subdomain enumeration are separate things. Reverse IP uses DNS PTR records, while subdomain enumeration uses [many different techniques](https://blog.sweepatic.com/art-of-subdomain-enumeration/)